# can I have logic code if else statements within catch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am not sure if this is right or wrong, but something deep inside me tells me that i am doing it wrong to have logic code on catch stm.
For ex my catch looks something like this:

```
      try{
       // do some stuff that throws some unexpected errors
      }
      catch (error) {
        if (error?.graphQLErrors[0]) {
          let msg = error.graphQLErrors[0].message
          switch (msg) {
              case 'limited':
              // TODO:: handle 
            default:
              window.location.href = "www.someurl.com";
          }
        }
```

Mainly I am thinking that catch stm usually should stay short and clean without logic on it that can cause another error or exception, what happens if the code inside catch throws some error?

Comment: "*what happens if the code inside catch throws some error*" well, you'd get an error. But your code honestly seems fine to me. Whether or not the logc is correct (redirect if you cannot handle) is a different matter.

Comment: Then it'll go to the next upper try / catch. If theres no upper catch, you might want to prevent errors in the catch block

Comment: There is nothing wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just fine to have logic in your `catch` block, if the logic is there in order to handle or report the error. That's what `catch` blocks are for.

> what happens if the code inside catch throws some error?

That's a *new* error. If you don't catch it, it will propagate to the caller, etc.

Example:

```js
function example() {
    try {
        // "x" has no method `foo` so this causes an error:
        "x".foo();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Caught error in \`example\`: ${e.message}`);
        // "y" has no method `bar` so this causes an error:
        "y".bar();
    }
}

function wrapper() {
    try {
        example();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Caught error in \`wrapper\`: ${e.message}`);
    }
}

wrapper();
```

Throwing errors *intentionally* from the `catch` block is a common practice in many places. You can wrap the original into one that can be better handled higher up or perhaps throw a more meaningful error

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(errorCode) {
    super();
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }
}

function example() {
    try {
        // "x" has no method `foo` so this causes an error:
        "x".foo();
    } catch (e) {
        throw new MyError(42);
    }
}

function wrapper() {
    try {
        example();
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.errorCode === 42) {//specific
          console.log(`I know what this error means: the flux capacitor is broken`);
        } else {//generic
          console.log(`Caught error in \`wrapper\`: ${e.message}`);
        }
    }
}

wrapper();
```

Answer (score 1):

> can I have logic code if else statements within catch statement?

Yes.

> what happens if the code inside catch throws some error?

The error will propagate to the next try catch block.

Comment: Why post an answer that just says what the already-posted answer says, but less completely?